# How to CSS visibility works

Tags: java, css

I put my whole code in https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/kuaen74m/5/

Trying to toggle the profile picture to reveal the menu in it but cannot.

the `html:`

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-menu">
                <div>
                    <div class="title">LOGG <span>Panel</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="action" onclick="menuToggle()">
                    <img src="img2.jpg">
                    <div class="propic">
                        <h3>My name <br><span>operator</span></h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i><span>Edit</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><span>Message</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i><span>Setting</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i><span>Help</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><span>Logout</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the action `class` is :

```
.wrapper .header .header-menu .action .propic {       
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
right: -10px;
padding: 10px 20px;
background: #ffffff;
width: 200px;
box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
border-radius: 15px;
transition: 0.5s;
    
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;    
}
    
.wrapper .header .header-menu .action .propic. active {visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Pls advise what missing in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the fact you have a css property overflow:hidden on the node with class name action

try replacing in your html with the following :

```
            <div class="action" onclick="menuToggle()">
                <div id="round">
                    <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="propic">
                    <h3>My name <br><span>operator</span></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i><span>Edit</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><span>Message</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i><span>Setting</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i><span>Help</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><span>Logout</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and then modify this part of the css :

```
.wrapper .header .header-menu .action {
    position: relative;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper .header .header-menu .action #round {
    position: relative;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I nested the image in a new div, moved the overflow hidden property to this div, then it works.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7whsca6/)

Comment: Hi, possible to collapse/hide the dropped-down menu when mouse is clicked anywhere on the page?

Comment: yes you could give a try to $(":not(.sidebar-btn)").click(menuToggle); in the javascript instead of placing onclick="menuToggle();" in the html

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden` on `.action`, this is preventing the children menu to be visible.

Once that is done, since the orange image is `absolute` positioned, it grows beyond its parent (because its `width` & `height` are `100px`).

To adjust this, you can move `border-radius: 50%` to `img` & change its `width` & `height` to `34px`, which is the same as `.action` (parent).

Edited CSS lines (in `.action` & `img`) are noted with comments below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sidebar-btn").click(function() {
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("kollapse");
  });
});

function menuToggle() {
  const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.propic')
  toggleMenu.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper .header {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #22242A;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 0%);
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu {
  width: calc(100% - 0%);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


/*text kiri atas*/

.wrapper .header .header-menu .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .title span {
  color: #4ccee8;
}


/*garis datar 3*/

.wrapper .header .header-menu .sidebar-btn {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 240px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition-property: color;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .sidebar-btn:hover {
  color: #4ccee8;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu ul {
  display: flex;
}


/*tombol sebelah my panel*/

.wrapper .header .header-menu ul li a {
  background: #ffff;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition-property: background, color;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #4ccee8;
  color: #fff;
}


/*************************************************************************/

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action {
  position: relative;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* removed these */
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */

}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* changed */
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  /* added */
  border-radius: 50%;
  
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action .propic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action .propic.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action .propic::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action .propic .h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action.propic h3 span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action.propic ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px soild rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action.propic ul li img {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action.propic ul li i {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action.propic ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action.propic ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .action.propic ul li :hover a {
  color: #ff5d94;
}


/*************************************************************************/

.wrapper .sidebar {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #2f323a;
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(100% - 9%);
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition-property: width;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .profile img {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .profile p {
  color: #bbb;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn {
  /**
    ini di nonaktifkan 
    display: block;
    **/
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 22px 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition-property: color;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn:hover {
  color: #4ccee8;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn i {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn .drop-down {
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu {
  background: #3498d8;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition-property: background, max-height;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*padding: 5px;
    padding : spasi_atas_bawah spasi_dari kiri
    */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8fc5e9;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition-property: background;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu a:hover {
  background: #55b1f0;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu i {
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item:target .sub-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
}

.wrapper .main-container {
  width: (100% - 250px);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  padding: 15px;
  /*
    background: url("images/background.jpg")no-repeat;*/
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.wrapper.kollapse .sidebar {
  width: 70px;
}

.wrapper.kollapse .sidebar .profile img,
.wrapper.kollapse .sidebar .profile p,
.wrapper.kollapse .sidebar a span {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.kollapse .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn {
  font-size: 23px;
}

.wrapper.kollapse .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu i {
  font-size: 38x;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.wrapper.kollapse .main-container {
  width: (100% - 70px);
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.wrapper .main-container .card {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/*responsive CSS*/

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .wrapper .sidebar {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .wrapper .sidebar .profile img,
  .wrapper .sidebar .profile p,
  .wrapper .sidebar a span {
    display: none;
  }
  .wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn {
    font-size: 23px;
  }
  .wrapper.sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu i {
    font-size: 38x;
    padding-left: 3px;
  }
  .wrapper .main-container {
    width: (100% - 70px);
    margin-left: 70px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <div>
        <div class="title">LOGG <span>Panel</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="action" onclick="menuToggle()">
        <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg">
        <div class="propic">
          <h3>My name <br><span>operator</span></h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i><span>Edit</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><span>Message</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i><span>Setting</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i><span>Help</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><span>Logout</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```